# Stripe invoicing customization partner

Tags: stripe-payments, invoice

I have finished integrating Stripe to my system and looking at the invoice generated, it misses a few details I would need to add.
As Stripe doesn't seem to offer the necessary customization on invoices yet I was wondering if I could use any of their partner before doing my own email implementation but there are too many and it's unclear how they would interact with my Stripe implementation.

So could anyone recommend one of those partner that would help me customize the invoice and JUST THAT, the stripe implementation is already done, it's just about the invoices.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what to recommend, but I'd start here:

https://stripe.com/works-with/categories/invoicing

Comment: I've looked into it but most of those looks more like a package Stripe + custom billing + other stuffs, All I want is the billing part as I already did the stripe implementation

Answer (score 0):

We recently went through the pain of invoice customization with stripe. I recommend using Stripe Custom or Standard accounts and sending invoices like this from your platform account:

```
$newInvoice=\Stripe\Invoice::create([
    "customer" => $customerID,
    "billing"=>$billing,
    "due_date"=>$dueDate,
    'auto_advance' => true,
    "tax_percent"=> $tax
],["stripe_account" => $conAccountID]);
```

You can customize the invoices from each connected account's dashboard.